# Failed to open stream using composer autoload

Tags: php, composer-php

I just included in the probject folder the phpmailer through composer running this command: `composer require phpmailer/phpmailer` inside the folder: `application/assets/`

I included in the index.php file the following command:

```
include 'application/assets/vendor/autoload.php';
```

but unfortunately I get this error:

> Warning: include(application/assets/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/projects/MyApp/index.php on line 74

this is the tree view of my application:

```
>MyApp
    >application  
       >assets
           >vendor
               >autoload.php
    >system  
    >index.php
```

inside the `vendor` folder I've `composer` and `phpmailer` folder, and if I include manually phpmailer class I doesn't get any error, this happen only when I include the composer autoload.

This is the content of `autoload.php`:

```
<?php

// autoload.php @generated by Composer

require_once __DIR__ . '/composer/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInit13c998efcdd189d437d19150f7ef3bc9::getLoader();
```

Comment: replace your `include` with `include __DIR__ . '/application/assets/vendor/autoload.php';`

Comment: @Federkun if I replace it I get this url: `/var/www/html/projects/MyApp/application/assets/vendor/autoload.php` and this error message: `Warning: require_once(/var/www/html/projects/MyApp/application/assets/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/projects/MyApp/application/assets/vendor/autoload.php on line 5`

Comment: have you removed/changed the contents inside the `composer` folder? run `composer update` again

Comment: @Federkun nope, just run the composer command to install the library phpmailer and include autoloader.php in index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if the installation in the subfolder `/application/assets/` is a must, but i'd suggest using the standard folder layout:

**Step1**
Create a `composer.json` next to your `index.php`

```
    \- MyApp
       \- application  
       \- system  
       \- index.php
       \- composer.json
```

Then add `phpmailer/phpmailer` into the require section of this `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "require": {
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^5.2"
    }
}
```

Then run `composer update`.

(Alternatively, you could also run `composer require phpmailer/phpmailer` in the `MyApp` folder. It will automatically generate the `composer.json` file for you)

The dependencies will be fetched into the folder: `vendors`, that means your folder structure looks like this now:

```
\ MyApp
  \ application  
  \ system 
  \ vendor          <-- new folder with composer autoloaders and dependencies
  \ index.php
  \ composer.json
```

**Step2**
Finally, add the Composer Autoloader to your `index.php`

```
    require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

That's it... start using your dependency: `$mail = new PHPMailer;`

Referencing:

- https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#installation--loading
- https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md